# Count the amount of matching values in excel

Tags: excel

In Excel I've got following four columns: [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKWZD.jpg).

In column C are the objects of column A filtered so only one example is shown. In column D I want the amount of matches shown.

For example: Banana has one text match with 'Bread', so I want the value one to appear. 
I've figured out I should use the formula: `=SUM(COUNTIF(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,SMALL(IF($C$2=$A$2:$A$11,ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW(1:1)))`
However, I would need multiple cells to achieve what I want.

Hopefully you can help me out!!

Comment: So what's your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To count the Fruits that has text matching only you can use the below code:

```
=SUM(IF((A:A=C2)*(B:B<>""),1,0))
```

assuming the same structure as the one in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think this is a simple [COUNTIFS](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,C2,B:B,"<>"&"")
```

for the first cell in column D, then just copy it down.

This counts everything where column A matches C2 (e.g., "Apple") **and** column B is not empty.

Here it is working:

[image]